# Folium map fill white gap in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I make a web app using Flask, in the body there are navbar and Folium map. It works fine in computer but when I try to open it in mobile phone, the map doesn't fill the entire screen. So I try to make this class

```
class React(MacroElement):
   _template = Template(u"""
            {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
              $(window).on("resize", function() {
                $("#{{this._parent.get_name()}}").height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());
                {{this._parent.get_name()}}.invalidateSize();
                }).trigger("resize");
            {% endmacro %}
            """) #noqa
   
   def __init__(self):
        super(React, self).__init__()
        self._name = 'React'
```

and then add to my map by `m.add_child(React())`. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Also I want to avoid using FullScreen Plugins. I've tried the CSS approach where you set the height and width of the ancestor container to 100% but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solved] By making the ancestors container `100vh` or `100%` then add this

```
fig = branca.element.Figure(height="100%")
fig.add_child(m)
```

I don't need the `React` class anymore

Comment: Can't handle it. Could you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here using Django.
The answer above worked for me as well for enlarging the map on small mobile devices.

`views.py`

```
import branca
"""..."""

def view(request):
    map = folium.Map()
    fig = branca.element.Figure(height='100%')
    fig.add_child(map)

    return render(request, "app/index.html", {'fig': fig._repr_html_()})
```

Inside the template (`index.html`) call the figure with the safe filter :

```
{{fig|safe}}
```